# Javascript RegEx required to substitute IPv4 and Port no in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as in:

```
  someCharactersHere andSomeMore  192.168.1.55 11211 typ someMorechars andYetMore
```

I know the IP address to be replaced but not the port number. I only know that it is an integer followed by "typ."
I am looking for JS to replace any such string by

```
  someCharactersHere andSomeMore  192.168.3.34 20121 typ someMorechars andYetMore
```

So, for example, a function to do so will be:

```
        function newString(oldString, oldIp, newIp, newPort) {
          
            return oldString.replace(/regEx/, newIp + " " + newPort);
         
        }
```

Can someone help me with the regEx. The IP address appears only once in the string. The integer port number may appear elsewhere but the one I want to replace will always be surrounded by a single space on the left and space followed by "typ" on the right. In other words the target to be replaced is:

```
         .... oldIp oldPortNo typ ...
```

by

```
         .... newIp newPortNo typ  ....
```

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/eKDtKc/3) help?

Comment: @Mandy8055  You do not have to validate the IP address or care for its content. It is just some string to be replaced by another string (for the purpose of this question).

Comment: @Mandy8055 Port number is always in between ipaddr and typ

Comment: @Mandy8055 Already got the simple answer I was looking for. Did upvote your comments.

Comment: No problem; I'm glad you got your problem solved =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to use a variable inside a regular expression:

```js
function newString(oldString, oldIp, newIp, newPort) {
  const regex = new RegExp(oldIp + "\\s+\\d+ typ");
  return oldString.replace(regex, newIp + " " + newPort + " typ");
}

const oldString = "someCharacters andSomeMore  192.168.1.55 11211 typ someMorechars",
      oldIp     = "192.168.1.55",
      newIp     = "192.168.3.34",
      newPort   = "20121";

console.log( newString(oldString, oldIp, newIp, newPort) );
```

This will look for the provided `oldIp`, followed by one or more space (`\s+`) and one or more digit `\d+`. And since `\` is an escape character in Strings, they need to be escaped themselves (`\\`).

Comment: Its close but "typ" must appear in the regular expression. That context is important.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3} \d+(?= typ)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching digits 1 to 3 times followed by a `.`. The whole group repeats exactly three times.
- **`\d{1,3}`** - Matches digit 1 to 3 times.(for the last part of IP)
- **`\d+(?= typ)`** - Matches digits which are followed by  `typ`.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/eKDtKc/6)

```js
const regex = /(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3} \d+(?= typ)/g;
const str = `someCharactersHere andSomeMore  192.168.1.55 11211 typ someMorechars andYetMore
`;
const subst = `192.168.3.34 20121`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex?

```
/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(\d+)\styp/gum
```

You can have a look at the regex101 fiddle here: https://regex101.com/r/Xk0gLR/1. Group 1 is the IP address, and Group 2 would be the port number

Answer (score 0):

\d+(.\d+)+\s+\d+

```js
s="someCharactersHere andSomeMore  123.123.123.123 123123 typ someMorechars andYetMore"

result=s.replace(/\d+(\.\d+)+\s+\d+/,'456.456.456.456 987987')

console.log(result)
```